# Deploy Two Wars to a Repository with One Pom

Tags: maven, software-distribution

I have a single project that builds two war files.  The only difference between the two are configuration files and the war name.  I'm trying to deploy the wars to our Nexus repository for distribution management.  I know how to name the wars differently in the pom by using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <buildVersion>counter</buildVersion>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>example_${buildVersion}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus.example</id>
        <url>https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/wars</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement></project>
```

But, when I run `mvn deploy`, the name of the war that is deployed doesn't have the buildVersion so both wars are named the same.

I've found the `deploy:deploy-file` directive, but it needs the version of the war that's being deployed defined as a -D spec.  Since I'm doing CD, I don't have the version on the command line within Bamboo.

Has anyone come across this situation before and what was done to accomplish it?

Comment: the `<finalName>..</finalName>` will only change the name within the `target` directory but will never change nor can change the name which is used to be deployed into a repository like Nexus...furthermore having a single pom and producing two war files? How are you doing this? Can you show the pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise I've updated the original post with the pom.  if we do a package with -DbuildVersion=blah, we can change the war name being built.

Comment: But you can't do this with a single build which in results means you will never be able to do this for a release version... The question is: Where is the difference between the war file?

Comment: I figured it couldn't be done with one build.  I was really hoping I could get around it.  I know how to do it with multiple builds and poms.  I just wanted to try and make it simpler.  

The only difference is in the configuration files and the war name.  Unfortunately this project is for a sister company and trying to update their code base and builds.  So I'm really limited in what I can do after deployment.  It would be the easiest if I could use a configuration server and have the code reach out to it.

Comment: I think it would be worth to take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin or the other solution is to create a multi module build with overlay mechanism to handle that....